# Getting an exception when trying to do data binding to an Enum on WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, enums

I'm trying to do some data binding to an enum on WPF, but I'm getting an exception.

1. First I have my NS declaration, pointing to the reference I have added to the project:

   `xmlns:defs="clr-namespace:API.Definitions;assembly=API"`

   and also:

   `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`
2. Then I'm adding an enum to the window resources:

   ```
   <Window.Resources
               <ResourceDictionary>
                   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="someEnum"
                                   MethodName="GetValues" 
                                   ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                       <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                           <x:Type TypeName="defs:someEnum" />
                       </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                   </ObjectDataProvider>
               </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. I'm trying to use it on a combo box:

   `ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource someEnum}}"`
4. Running it and getting a XamlParseException:

`Type reference cannot find type named '{clr namespace:API.Definitions;assembly=API}someEnum'.`

I have browsed this API reference and I can clearly see that enum and use
it on code if I'd like.  I have also tested binding to a local enum (not referenced),
and this works perfectly.

Some answers implied that removing the assembly=API from xmlns:defs="clr-namespace:API.Definitions;assembly=API" should solve this, but it doesn't.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure about the enum type name? Is it really `someEnum` or perhaps `SomeEnum`? I get exactly your error message when the type does not exist in the referenced assembly. Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: Absolutely positive.  To make things even weirder, I have another solution that has the same referenced assembly and the same XAML lines of code as described above. However, the referenced assembly in the other solution is also an added project. Everything works find in that case, but I can't get it to work when it's a .dll.

Comment: Still works for me if i also do that. Could you try to access that `someEnum` from code-behind?

Comment: Already have, and it works.  What am I missing? :(

Comment: Is the reference DLL copied where your code can access it? Most likely in  the "bin\debug" project folder.

Comment: Yes, it's in the bin/debug and it's accessible via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found what was causing it -- the referenced API was built for x86 rather than "Any CPU".  Any explanation for this?

Comment: That's because the WPF Designer is x86 based.